# Express Server continuously throws 404 error

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, server

I keep getting these errors.
[image]

Here's some of my code.

**bin/www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var eventsRouter = require('./routes/events');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
  next();
});

app.use('/dashboard', eventsRouter);
app.use('/user', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   next(createError(404));
// });

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

mongoose.connect('// this is good just deleted for post')
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database!");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Connection failed.")
  });

module.exports = app;
```

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const router = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then(hash => {
      const user = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        userName: req.body.userName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash
      });
      user.save()
        .then(result => {
          res.status(201).json({
            msg: "User Created",
            rslt: result
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(500).json({
            err: err
          });
        });
    });
});

router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  let fetchedUser;
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          msg: "Auth Failed."
        });
      }
      fetchedUser = user;
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    })
    .then(result => {
      if (!result) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          msg: "Auth Failed."
        });
      }
      const token = jwt.sign(
        { email: fetchedUser.email, userId: fetchedUser._id },
        // ,
        { expiresIn: '1h' }
      );
      res.status(200).json({
        token: token
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(401).json({
        msg: err
      });
    });
});

router.post("/profile", (req, res, next) => {

})

module.exports = router;
```

**events.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const Event = require('../models/event');
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/check-auth');

router.post("/createEvent", checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  const event = new Event({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    date: req.body.date,
    time: req.body.time,
    location: req.body.location,
    invite: req.body.invite,
    private: req.body.private
  });
  event.save()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(201).json({
        msg: "Event Created",
        rslt: result
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        err: err
      });
    });

});
module.exports = router;
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong. It's a project that I started a couple of months ago and of course, didn't finish it. I just recently came back to it and can't seem to figure out why my server won't work. Seems to connect fine with the database.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your typing '/' url, but in your code there is no '/' route.

Can you add the 'home' route as following, and check again please ?

```
app.use('/dashboard', eventsRouter);
app.use('/user', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   next(createError(404));
// });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('home');
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Comment: I got no errors and home is displayed on the screen. However, I still can't use my localhost:3000/dashboard nor localhost:3000/user route.

Comment: @RickyMed soo share the content of this two files, maybe is there any issue inside it...

Comment: I just updated the post. Although I can't even go to localhost:3000/user. Much less localhost:3000/user/signup.

Answer (score 0):

@RickyMed have you defined any middleware for `/` route. Generally `404 Not Found` came when url is not present. If not create one or try `http://localhost:3000/user`.
Check if this is working

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. And the solution suggested by Benard Patrick works for localhost:3000 but can't display my other routes.

Comment: @RickyMed check if call is going into those listeners that you have defined. Do some console logging and check whether you are sending any res back

Comment: I'm trying to listen but doesn't even compile the code anymore when I tried to.